# PlayOnLinux - Steam - Chivalry Medieval Warfare - Microsoft VC redist Loop

Tags: wine, steam, playonlinux, dotnet

I recently switched to ubuntu and so far I think it is amazing!

I am trying to run the game Chivalry Medieval Warfare on a Windows Client of Steam through Wine/PlayOnLinux.
The game downloaded okay but when I press play it takes me to the "first time setup" window because it wants to install Microsoft VC redist. the window abruptly closes after about 8 minutes, with no results. This happens over and over and I cannot get past the First Time Setup.

I installed these components in PoL:
dxfullsetup
dotNet40

Presumable that is what it is trying to download.
If I look in the Chivalry local files there is an setup file for dotNet 4.5. which isn't listed in PoL.
Someone said that adding a override for d3dx11 in wine and setting it to disable. That did not solve my problem.

Does anyone have any insights into this matter? I want to avoid duel booting if possible. I can do that if it comes down to it, assuming it's possible to duel boot windows 7 even when ubuntu was there first

Answer (score 0):

Go into the game's properties, and click on "Browse Local Files". Click on `_CommonRedist` and go to `vcredist`. Click on `2010` and run both executables located under there. This worked for me, I don't know if it'll work for you, but I'm happy to help!